# How do I get a part of the output of a command in Linux Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

How do I get a part of the output of a command in Bash?

For example, the command `php -v` outputs:

```
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2014 16:25:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

And I only want to output the `PHP 5.3.28 (cli)` part. How do I do that?

I've tried `php -v | grep 'PHP 5.3.28'`, but that outputs: `PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2014 16:25:09)` and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try the below [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) command,

```
$ php -v | awk 'NR==1{print $1,$2,$3}'
PHP 5.3.28 (cli)
```

It prints the first three columns from the first line of input.

- `NR==1` (condition)ie, execute the statements within `{}` only if the value of NR variable is 1.
- `{print $1,$2,$3}` Print col1,col2,col3. `,` in the print statement means OFS (output field separator).

Comment: It works, but I don't understand what you're doing. Could you explain that?

Comment: Oh, wait, I understand it now! :) Thanks a ton..!

Answer (score 4):

In pure Bash you can do

```
echo 'PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2014 16:25:09)' | cut -d '(' -f 1,2
```

Output:

```
PHP 5.3.28 (cli)
```

Or using space as the delimiter:

```
echo 'PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2014 16:25:09)' | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

> a classic "million ways to skin a cat" question...

These methods seem to filter by spaces... If the versions/notes contain spaces, this fails.

The `(` brackets, however, seem consistent across all my platforms so I've used the following:

For example, on [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian):

```
root@host:~# php -v  | head -1
PHP 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Dec 13 2013 01:38:56)
root@host:~# php -v  | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 1-2
PHP 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0
```

So here I trim everything before the second `(`:

```
root@host:~# php -v  | head -1 | cut -d "(" -f 1-2
PHP 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)
```

**Note**: there will be a trailing white-space (blank space at the end)

Alternatively, you could always use your package manager to determine this (recommended):

```
root@debian-or-ubuntu-host:~# dpkg -s php5 | grep 'Version'
Version: 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0
```

...or on a [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux), or [Scientific Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Linux) distribution:

```
[root@rpm-based-host ~]# rpm -qa | grep php-5
php-5.4.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the lines that contain "php", do this:

```
 $ php -v | grep -i "php"
```

Then if you want the first three words within those, you can add another pipe as @Avinash suggested:

```
$ php -v | grep -i "php" | awk 'NR==1{print $1,$2,$3}'
```